# scrapy : scrape multiple items from 2 levels

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm fairly new to scrapy and I'm looking for a solution for my personal exercise. What I'm trying to do is to crawl IMDB top chart movies to get the ranking, the title, the year, and the plot.
I manage to go through the links and crawl the movie pages but I can't find a way to get the ranking for each movie.

Currently my code looks like this :

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import IMDB_dict # We need this so that Python knows about the item object

class MppaddressesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "mppaddresses" # The name of this spider

# The allowed domain and the URLs where the spider should start crawling:
allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/']

def parse(self, response):
    # The main method of the spider. It scrapes the URL(s) specified in the
    # 'start_url' argument above. The content of the scraped URL is passed on
    # as the 'response' object.
    for rank in response.xpath(".//tbody[@class='lister-list']/tr/td[@class='titleColumn']/text()").extract():
        rank=" ".join(rank.split())
        item = IMDB_dict()
        item['rank'] = rank

    for url in response.xpath(".//tbody[@class='lister-list']/tr/td[@class='titleColumn']/a/@href").extract():
        # This loops through all the URLs found inside an element of class 'mppcell'

        # Constructs an absolute URL by combining the response’s URL with a possible relative URL:
        full_url = response.urljoin(url)
        print("FOOOOOOOOOnd URL: "+full_url)

        # The following tells Scrapy to scrape the URL in the 'full_url' variable
        # and calls the 'get_details() method below with the content of this
        # URL:
        #yield {'namyy' : response.xpath(".//tbody[@class='lister-list']/tr/td[@class='titleColumn']/text()").extract().strip("\t\r\n '\""),}
        yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.get_details)

def get_details(self, response):
    # This method is called on by the 'parse' method above. It scrapes the URLs
    # that have been extracted in the previous step.

    #item = OntariomppsItem() # Creating a new Item object
    # Store scraped data into that item:
    item = IMDB_dict()
    item['name'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='title_bar_wrapper']/div[@class='titleBar']/div[@class='title_wrapper']/h1/text()").extract_first().strip("\t\r\n '\"")
    item['phone'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='titleBar']/div[@class='title_wrapper']/h1/span[@id='titleYear']/a/text()").extract_first().strip("\t\r\n '\"")
    item['email'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='plot_summary ']/div[@class='summary_text']/text()").extract_first().strip("\t\r\n '\"")
    # Return that item to the main spider method:
    yield item
```

Besides, my item.py has:

```
import scrapy

class IMDB_dict(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    rank = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    phone = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
```

**Main question:** How can I get the ranking associated with the title?

**Last question (if possible):** I can access URLs like I did when URLs are relative (with urljoin), but I can't find a way to access URLs when they are absolute...

Many thanks for your help.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `rank` to your `get_details` callback using `meta`:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for movie in response.xpath(".//tbody[@class='lister-list']/tr/td[@class='titleColumn']"):

        movie_rank = movie.xpath('./text()').re_first(r'(\d+)')

        movie_url = movie.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()
        movie_full_url = response.urljoin(movie_url)
        print("FOOOOOOOOOnd URL: " + movie_url)

        yield scrapy.Request(movie_full_url, callback=self.get_details, meta={"rank": movie_rank})

def get_details(self, response):

    item = IMDB_dict()        
    item['rank'] = response.meta["rank"]
    item['name'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='title_bar_wrapper']/div[@class='titleBar']/div[@class='title_wrapper']/h1/text()").extract_first().strip("\t\r\n '\"")
    item['phone'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='titleBar']/div[@class='title_wrapper']/h1/span[@id='titleYear']/a/text()").extract_first().strip("\t\r\n '\"")
    item['email'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='plot_summary ']/div[@class='summary_text']/text()").extract_first().strip("\t\r\n '\"")
    # Return that item to the main spider method:
    yield item
```

***UPDATE***
If you check logs you'll find this error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Sometimes `.extract_first()` returns `None` and you can't `strip()` it. I recommend you to use [Scrapy Item Loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works great ! It actually answered both my questions. However, I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't crawl some of the movies. I tried running the crawler few times but I am missing the same movies. HTML code does seem to be exactly the same. Number 22, 34, 44, 65, and some others are not crawled. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Hi Gangabass, Thanks for your update. I am working on the item loaders, and have a bunch to learn about. FYI, I tried to upvote your answer, but it seems like I am too new on the website to do that. Again, many thanks for your thorough contribution.

Comment: UPDATE : Actually figured out the reason why number 22, 34, etc. were not crawled. Reason is IMDB, for some movies, changes the summary text's class and adds a new class. Therefore the xpath is no longer correct and the output is an empty string. 
In order the solve this, I needed to change the xpath of the summary to 'contains the class' instead of 'has the class'. 
New xpath : item['email'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='plot_summary_wrapper']/div[contains(@class,'plot_summary')]/div[@class='summary_text']/text()").extract_first().strip("\t\r\n '\"")